# Library for matching next song by mood

Tags: algorithm, audio

Are there any librarys for mood matching a song. i.e. some algorithm to finger print every song and shuffle the list by my mood(the current playing file(s))?

Cheers,
Mark

Comment: You mean extracting the information, which mood a song might be suitable for, just from the raw audio?!

Comment: @zerm yes, one crude way would be get the average BPM and match on that. I would like to enable such a feature in my media app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this hard to believe, but "There's an app for that".  [MoodAgent](http://www.moodagent.com/) apparently does what you're talking about.  You might be able to download it and do some reverse engineering based on the capabilities already in the software.

Thanks for the question - it made me find what could be an interesting piece of software.

Comment: Thankyou and your welcome :D! I fancy adding such a feature to my carpc media front end. It's easyer finding what you want by skipping the songs that you dont want.Especially when your eyes have to be looking at the road!

Answer (score 0):

Heres some interesting things I have found
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_fingerprint
http://ismir2003.ismir.net/papers/Liu.PDF